# angular compiler syntax issue

Tags: javascript, angular

As per this link: https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/correlation-id

I am trying as below, but getting compile error, may I know how to fix below?

```
import {withId} from 'correlation-id'

withId.withId(() => {withId.getId();}); //getting compile error here
```

Comment: Did you install the package using npm?

Comment: @nicolascolman yes, I did, there is something wrong in above syntax, can u able to help me out..?

Comment: try changing {withId.getId();} by {console.log(withId.getId());}

Answer (score 0):

you should to declare object - class ? export it. If it is an TS.
export class Foo {
}

Comment: am getting compiler error at this line:  withId.withId(() => {withId.getId();});
  May i know whats the fix?